# Create a map from a list of maps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of maps.

```
List<Map<Integer, String>>
```

The values in the list are, for example

```
<1, String1>
<2, String2>
<1, String3>
<2, String4>
```

As an end result, I want a Map>, like

```
<1, <String1, String3>>
<2, <String2, String4>>
```

How can I achieve this in Java.

CODE :

```
List<Map<Integer, String>> genericList = new ArrayList<Map<Integer,String>>();
for(TrackActivity activity : activityMajor){
Map<Integer, String> mapIdResponse = activity.getMapIdResponse();
genericList.add(mapIdResponse);
}
```

Now this genericList is the input and from this list, based on the same ids I want a

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapIdResponseList
```

Basically, to club the responses which are String based on the ids, grouping the responses with same id in a list and then creating a new map with that id as the key and the list as its value.

Comment: `Map<Integer,<String,String>>`

Comment: So you're storing only one key-value pair in each map? It seems to me that a custom object would have been enough.

Comment: As I see you want `Map<Integer, List<String>>`.

Comment: The maps in the list have common keys but different values. I want to group these common values in a list and put that list in a new map<Integer, List<String>> with the common key as the key in the new map and the list<String> as its value.

Comment: Do you need the `<String1, String3>` to end up in an object, or is it ok to have them en dup in a `List<String>` aswell?

Comment: Moreover, your values in the list do not make sense to me. It looks like you have `List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>`, which is (almost) equivalent to `Map<Integer, String>`, please clarify once again.

Comment: A List<String> will be okay.

Comment: To me it seems like you really want to have a `Map<Integer, String>` as input and have a grouped `Map<Integer, List<String>>` in the end, is that correct?

Comment: It is a list of maps. The map has the arguments <Integer, String>.

Comment: Yes, exactly the grouping needs to be done based on the keys. I cannot loop over the map as the data set is too large and that many iterations is not optimal.

Comment: @Aayush Please add compilable code to the question, which demonstrates the *list of maps* where you are thinking about, I think I know the answer, but I do not exactly know how your code looks like.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it the following with Java 8:

```
private void init() {
    List<Map<Integer, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, "String1");
    mapList.add(map1);

    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(2, "String2");
    mapList.add(map2);

    Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put(1, "String3");
    mapList.add(map3);

    Map<Integer, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
    map4.put(2, "String4");
    mapList.add(map4);

    Map<Integer, List<String>> response = mapList.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Map.Entry::getKey, 
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                    Collectors.toList()
                            )
                    )
            );
    response.forEach((i, l) -> {
        System.out.println("Integer: " + i + " / List: " + l);
    });
}
```

This will print:

> Integer: 1 / List: [String1, String3]
>   Integer: 2 / List: [String2, String4]

Explanation (heavily warranted), I am afraid I cannot explain every single detail, you need to understand the basics of the `Stream` and `Collectors` API introduced in Java 8 first:

1. Obtain a `Stream<Map<Integer, String>>` from the `mapList`.
2. Apply the `flatMap` operator, which roughly maps a stream into an already existing stream.
   Here: I convert all `Map<Integer, String>` to `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>` and add them to the existing stream, thus now it is also of type `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>`.
3. I intend to collect the `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>` into a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`.
4. For this I will use a `Collectors.groupingBy`, which produces a `Map<K, List<V>>` based on a grouping function, a `Function` that maps the `Map.Entry<Integer, String>` to an `Integer` in this case.
5. For this I use a method reference, which exactly does what I want, namely `Map.Entry::getKey`, it operates on a `Map.Entry` and returns an `Integer`.
6. At this point I would have had a `Map<Integer, List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>>` if I had not done any extra processing.
7. To ensure that I get the correct signature, I must add a downstream to the `Collectors.groupingBy`, which has to provide a collector.
8. For this downstream I use a collector that maps my `Map.Entry` entries to their `String` values via the reference `Map.Entry::getValue`.
9. I also need to specify how they are being collected, which is just a `Collectors.toList()` here, as I want to add them to a list.
10. And this is how we get a `Map<Integer, List,String>>`.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at guavas MultiMap. Should be exactly what you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Comment: thanks but I am looking for a way to do this without adding an extra library.